# how i write mqtt URL in python 3

Tags: python, mqtt

i new to python 3 and raspberry and im doing an IOT project where i use mqtt app to turn off led from my raspberry
i got the code with python 2 but im sill new so i didnt know how to change the follwing functions

```
import urlparse


url_str = os.environ.get('CLOUDMQTT_URL', 'tcp://broker.emqx.io:1883') 
url = urlparse.urlparse(url_str)
mqttc.connect(url.hostname, url.port)
```

i have the full code too
This is my first question here sorry for bad explanation or writing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71770466/edit) the question to show what error/problem you get with the code you have shown.